# Why isn't my dropdown menu firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think something may be wrong with my head, but I'm not sure what

```
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="resources/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>
```

Here is my navbar:

```
<nav>
                <div id="top" class="row">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="resources/css/img/brand1.png" class="logo"></a>
                    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                        <li><a id="workout" href="#">The Workout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trainers</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">About Level Red</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">The 6 Punches</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Buy Classes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="accountButton">My Account</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

No dropdowns on my website are working, and I have reason to believe it has to do with the order or what is in my head section.

EDIT:

I am getting this console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])
    at Function.ga.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ga.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ga [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at r (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:28)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Try to put that script `<script src="resources/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js">` just below the jquery library `</script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: @SKJajoriya Didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5ufkzcku/) is working fine.

Comment: There might be compatibility issues with version of jQuery. try using 2.x jquery and see if that makes any difference. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> . Also I do know whats wrong with your head; you are a eagles fan. jk.

Answer (score 0):

i only load this libraries whit your example and works:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

probably the problem is you must load Jquery waypoints after load Jquery. No console errors?

Comment: I tried what you said with no luck. Please see my edit for the console error.

Comment: do you look at this: 
`at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:28)` 
looks like an error in your embebed javascript